# Recognize a sort order in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with items that are booked together and in a certain order. This results in a table with a data set like this.

```
id item_id group_id 
 1     1        1
 2     2        1
 3     3        1
 4     1        2
 5     2        2
 6     3        2
 7     2        3
 8     1        3
 9     3        3
10     3        4
11     2        4
12     1        4
13     1        5
14     2        5
15     3        5
16     4        5
 .
 .
 .
```

Now, I am looking for a query (or multiple) that finds the different sort orders within the groups and that can indicate the dominant one. In this case the answer should be something like:

```
group_id order_used_nr_times
     1        3
     2        3
     3        1
     4        1
     5        3
     .             
     .             
     .
```

Note, as group 5 indicates, it is well possible that more items exist within the group and that the searched items are a subset (e.g.,looking for order of items 4,5,6 and found in 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 is an option.

I've been thinking about a query with group and having or something with mysql transpose but I can't get my head around it.

Additional info:

I need the query to give me the dominant sort order (this case `1,2,3`) so it can be used to insert a new group that consists of the items `1,2,3` ordered `1,2,3` and not `2,1,3` or `3,2,1,` in this example.

From a business perspective: There are two "groups of people" using the system, group A and Group B. Group A knows how to order the items, therefore sets the order manually and the systems just inserts the data in the given order. Group B however, doesn't know the order. Therefore the system (query) needs to look if Group A already booked these items and if so, in which order they occurs most often (order can differ as the example shows). The order from group A will then be used to insert the data from group B assuming this is the most logical.

I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: I think using variables will be the solution http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, a simple group by should suffice: `SELECT COUNT(*), group_id FROM MyTable GROUP BY COUNT(*)`

Comment: can you expand some more on how you get from your sample data to your expected output, please? Been staring at this for a few mins now and still don't get what you want....

Comment: I have no idea what you're after.

Comment: And what if there are `1,2,3`, `4,5,6` and `1,2,3,4,5,6`? Should the first two be considered the same because both are found in the third one?

Comment: @cbeckner, MYSQL says, invalid use of group function. and I am afraid I don't get the group by count(*) since it seems we count everything.

Comment: @AndriyM, yes, these could be considered the same although the change it actually occurs is minimal. As an additional not: it is not the same the other way around. Say looking for `1,2,3,4,5,6` and than use two different groups `1,2,3,` and `3,4,5`. That would be incorrect.

Comment: I'm just struggling to understand the logic behind `order_used_nr_times = 3` for `group_id = 5`. That group consists of `1,2,3,4`. For the source data sample shown, there is not one other group containing the same set of items, so why 3? Merely because there are two `1,2,3`s? But then why are you saying that, when looking for `1,2,3,4,5,6`, groups like `1,2,3` or `3,4,5` should not be considered? That is precisely the same situation!

Comment: @AndriyM, Because the items `1,2,3` are in the set their order is relevant. If this makes it to complex, we can also skip these. The question remains the same. but i'm working on a solution.

Comment: You mean with ordering: the rank of the `id` field when you order by item_id (per group_id) ? That would need a window function (which mysql does not have, hard to work around), and the question should also be tagged `relational division` in that case. BTW: group_id=5 has the same ordering as group one and two, just one more item added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find counts for identical groups. You could first group the rows by `group_id` and GROUP_CONCAT the `item_id` values:

```
SELECT
  group_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY id) AS item_list
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  group_id
;
```

That would give you a result set like this:

```
group_id  item_list
--------  ---------
1         1,2,3
2         1,2,3
3         2,1,3
4         3,2,1
5         1,2,3,4
```

It is easy now to get the number of entries for every distinct item list:

```
SELECT
  item_list,
  COUNT(*) AS nr_times
FROM (
  SELECT
    group_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY id) AS item_list
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY
    group_id
) AS s
GROUP BY
  item_list
;
```

And the query returns:

```
item_list  nr_times
---------  --------
1,2,3      2
1,2,3,4    1
2,1,3      1
3,2,1      1
```

This is not the output you are after, as you need the counts next to group IDs. Therefore, the last row set needs to be joined to the previous row set:

```
SELECT
  groups.group_id,
  counts.nr_times
FROM (
  SELECT
    group_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY id) AS item_list
  FROM atable
  GROUP BY group_id
) AS groups
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    item_list,
    COUNT(*) AS nr_times
  FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY id) AS item_list
    FROM atable
    GROUP BY group_id
  ) AS s
  GROUP BY item_list
) AS counts
ON groups.item_list = counts.item_list
;
```

The output:

```
group_id  nr_times
--------  --------
1         2
2         2
3         1
4         1
5         1
```

At this point, it is obvious that grouping the same set twice may not be a very good idea. Perhaps it would be better to store the results of the first grouping to a temporary table, then use it to get the final result:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_results
AS
SELECT
  group_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY id) AS item_list
FROM atable
GROUP BY
  group_id
;

SELECT
  groups.group_id,
  counts.nr_times
FROM temp_results AS groups
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    item_list,
    COUNT(*) AS nr_times
  FROM temp_results
  GROUP BY item_list
) AS counts
ON groups.item_list = counts.item_list
;
```

Now to get the figures as in your desired output, you could try matching the two sets with LIKE, like this:

```
SELECT
  groups.group_id,
  counts.nr_times
FROM temp_results AS groups
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    item_list,
    COUNT(*) AS nr_times
  FROM temp_results
  GROUP BY item_list
) AS counts
ON CONCAT(',', groups.item_list, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', counts.item_list, ',%')
OR CONCAT(',', counts.item_list, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', groups.item_list, ',%')
;
```

The above would give you the following:

```
group_id  nr_times
--------  --------
1         2
1         1
2         2
2         1
3         1
4         1
5         2
5         1
```

Apparently, you now only need to stick

```
GROUP BY groups.group_id
```

at the end of the last query and replace the `counts.nr_times` in its SELECT clause with

```
SUM(counts.nr_times) AS order_used_nr_times
```

to get the same output as in your question:

```
group_id  order_used_nr_times
--------  -------------------
1         3
2         3
3         1
4         1
5         3
```

Note, however, that if you have groups with items `1,2,3`, `3,4,5`, and `1,2,3,4,5,6`, the LIKE joining condition used in the last query will match either of the first two groups with the third one only and not with each other, while the third group will be matched with both of the first two groups.

I am not sure whether that satisfies your requirements because I am still unable to make out your explanations on that particular point (sorry). I do hope that this post can at least give you some ideas how to arrive at the right results eventually.

Comment: whow, impressive! What a great explanation and it is spot on what i've been looking for! I now sort the final result set, use the concatenated id's and use an ORDER BY FIELD(item_id, item_list) on insert and have the ID's stored in the most common way. Perfect, thank you so much!